# Make a java app start when the PC starts

Tags: java

I have been creating a java application, and I would like to have it started up when the computer starts up. I have seen some people asking the same question, but they did it with a batch file, or an installer.

I would like to know if it is possible to do this in java, and if it is, what the script would be.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For windows: Maybe just copy it into the autostart folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this to be in Windows in your startup directory create a bat file like this:

```
@javaw -jar path/to/jar/MyName.jar args
```

Or you can also use the [Java Wrapper Service](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html) and edit the [configurations](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-ntservice-starttype.html) accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Java based way to achieve this.

The library Apache Daemon allows to create a Java App that behaves as a Service.

Windows and Unix-based OS are supported.

[Apache Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/)